# Metric on a manifold with boundary, with prescribed orthogonal

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, transversality

Let $M$ be a compact manifold with boundary $\partial M$. Suppose that we are given a hyper surface $A$ which is transversal to $\partial M$.

Is there a way to construct a metric $g$ on $M$ such that for any $x \in A \cap \partial M$, we have
$$
T_x \partial M^{\perp_g} \subset T_x A ?
$$ 
In other words, can we force the orthogonal of the boundary to lie in a prescribed hypersurface ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.